# Python class inheritance - Base is modified by a subclass

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance

Let's say I have a class called `Test` with an attribute items. Then I create a subclass called `Best`. Which has a method that modifies the classes attribute items. But it even modifies `Test`'s `items` and I what it to modify `items` only for `Best`.

```
class Test():
    items = []

class Best(Test):
    def method(self):
        type(self).items.append("a test")

>>> Best().method()
>>> Best.items
["a test"]
>>> Test.items 
["a test"]            # This is what I don't want.
```

Comment: Is `Best` supposed to inherit from `Test`?

Comment: Yes it is, I did not test my example code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way to do this is to create a new `items` on the subclass -- where else is this new list meant to come from? Also `type(self)` is redundant. The lookup machinery looks up attributes on the class if it cannot find the attribute on the instance. Better yet, if you don't need an instance then declare the method to be a class method.

eg.

```
class Test:
    items = []
    @classmethod
    def method_test(cls):
        cls.items.append('test')

class Best(Test):
    items = []
    @classmethod
    def method_best(cls):
        cls.items.append('best')

Test.method_test()

assert Test.items == ['test']
assert Best.items == []

Test.items = []
Best.method_test()
Best.method_best()

assert Test.items == []
assert Best.items == ['test', 'best']
```

Note that `method_test` works on the `Best` class when called from the `Best` class.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `items` as an attribute of the superclass itself, so all instances of Test and it's subclasses will share the same list.  Instead declare it in Test's __ init __ method, so there is one list per instance.

In Best, just append to `self.items`, and only the Best instance's list will be updated.

```
class Test(object):
    def __ init __(self)
        self.items = []

class Best(Test):    # Best must inherit from Test
    def method(self):
        self.items.append("a test")
```

Comment: This would be an attribute of it's instances not of the class.

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can get what you are asking by using "private" members...

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__mine = 42  # note the double underscore
    def baseMethod(self):
        return self.__mine

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        self.__mine = 99

    def derivedMethod(self):
        return self.__mine

obj = Derived()
print(obj.baseMethod(), obj.derivedMethod()) ## ==> 42, 99
```

this works because **at compile time** Python will replace the name `__mine` with `_Base__mine` when compiling `Base` and with `_Derived__mine` when compiling `Derived`.

Note however that in Python while this is possible in my experience it's not used very often. Deriving a class in many cases is just not needed thanks to "duck typing" and to delegation, something that is not possible in languages like C++ or Java.

Comment: OK I will try. Thank you.

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted but it still helps me with a diffrient thing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Best` class is modifying `Test` (which I assume it's supposed to be inheriting from) because `Best` doesn't have its own `items` list. When you access `Best.items`, you're accessing the list where it is inherited from (i.e. from `Test` class). If you want a different list, you need to create it explicitly in the subclass `Best`:

```
class Best(Test):
    items = [] # hide the inherited list with our own list

    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do what you describe.

For one thing, `Best` is not a subclass of `Test`.

For another `Best.method()` produces

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

`items` is a `Test` class attribute.

```
t = Test()
t.items.append(1)
```

changes `Test.items`.

As defined `B.items` gives an `AttributeError`.

Even if I change:

```
class Best():
    def method(self):
        ...
```

`Best.method()` does not run; `method` is an instance method.  I need to use `Best().method()`.  But then I get the `items` `AttributeError`.

```
 class Best(Test):
    def method(self):
        ...
```

does what you desribe. `Best().method()` modifies the `Test.items` - because the `Test` class attribute is shared with the subclass.

As shown in other answers, simply defining `items` for `Best` decouples its value from the `Test` class attribute

```
 class Best(Test):
     items = ['other']
     ...
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not test the example code. I edited the question. Thanks.